# Flex 4 - Define a style for html links in CSS

Tags: html, css, apache-flex, hyperlink

It's been 2 hours that I'm trying to do this, I never thought it would be such a nightmare, and Google isn't helping me at all.

Does anybody know how can I define a CSS style for html hyperlinks inside a `mx|Label` component such as `a`, `a:link`, `a:hover` and `a:active` ?

(*I can't use s|Label since it doesn't dispatch `link` events...*)

I tried everything (even really stupid ones), but am unable to find anything that actually works:

```
mx|Label.a {...}
mx|Label a {...}
mx|Label:a {...}
a {...}
mx|Label.a:link {...}
mx|Label a:link {...}
mx|Label:a:link {...}
a:link {...}
*|a {...}
*|a:link {...}
mx|a {...}
mx|a:link {...}
```

None of these are working, and I didn't found any help anywhere, nobody seems to have encountered this issue.

I'll be extremely grateful if someone could help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only working solution I found is setting the styles manually using ActionScript :

```
var styleSheet:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
styleSheet.parseCSS( "a:hover { color: #6666ff; text-decoration: underline; } a { color: #0000ff; }" );
label.styleSheet = styleSheet;
```

...which I find pretty ugly (mixing .css file with hard-coded styles...)

Somebody got anything nicer?

Comment: Well, seems like it's the only solution =/